# Listing ads from database with correct ID's from a certain user

Tags: php, database

**So I have the following SQLQuery:**

```
$user = new User();
$nome = escape($user->data()->username);
$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","publicidade") or die("Erro MySQL");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ads, users WHERE users.username = '$nome' AND users.id = ads.cod_user";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
```

**Following then the current code to list:**

```
while(($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) != null)
    {
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $registo["id"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["content"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["image"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["total_views"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["contract_views"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["active"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["cod_type"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registo["cod_organization"]?></td>
            <td><a href="editAd.php?id=<?php echo $registo["id"]; ?>">ALTERAR</a></td>
            <td><a href="removeAd.php?id=<?php echo $registo["id"]; ?>">REMOVER</a></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
```

There's one thing I want, which is listing the whole ads made by that user (it works) but with the correct ID's, which in my case would be something like "**1**" "**3**" "**6**" "**9**". The problem is that it's listing them but with the user ID "**1**" instead.

```
<td><?php echo $registo["id"]?></td>
```

Should I change something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either split up the `*` into the exact list while of columns refering the table name and give the ads.id a special name: `SELECT ... , ads.id as AdID FROM ...`

Or you could change the name of the id-column in one of the tables. That would force you to change it everywhere it's used aswell. Therefor I'd go with option one.

Comment: Oh, changed the "users.id" to "users.id as usersId" as the example you gave and it works now. Thank you very much.